# Why (e.g.) a \strutbox and a (expl3) \vbox_set:Nn box containing this \strutbox don't have the same height?

Tags: boxes, expl3, dimensions

As shown by the following MCE, a `\strutbox` and a (`expl3`) `\vbox_set:Nn` box containing this `\strutbox` don't have the same height. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \strutbox }

The~ height~ of
\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\strutbox|~ is:~ \dim_use:N \box_ht:N \strutbox
\item \verb|\l_tmpa_box|~ is:~ \dim_use:N \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box
\end{itemize}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Same would be true with `\setbox0\vbox{\strutbox}\the\ht0 `.

Comment: @Skillmon Good to know but I don't understand better :)

Comment: Use `\vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \box_use:N \strutbox }` instead and compare the heights then.

Comment: `\dim_use:n { \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }` would be the correct syntax; `\dim_use:N` should be followed by a single token that represents a length variable. Your `\dim_use:N \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box` only works by chance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This has nothing to do with `expl3` boxes, so this answer uses plain TeX box syntax.)

With normal settings, `\strutbox` is just a cleverly stored integer, the `\meaning` of that macro is:

```
\strutbox:
\char"B
```

So what happens if you're using `\setbox\mybox\vbox{\strutbox}` is the same as if you did `\setbox\mybox\vbox{\char"B}` (so this prints the character from slot 11, in Computer Modern this is the `ff`-ligature).

If you want to insert a `\strutbox`, you'd use `\copy\strutbox` or `\unhcopy\strutbox` (the latter is used by the macro `\strut` in text mode, the former in maths mode).

When you do `\the\ht\strutbox`, this is the same as `\the\ht11` (so the height of box register 11), but when you do `\setbox\mybox\vbox{\strutbox}` you're comparing that to the height of character slot 11, not to the height of the `\strutbox`.

To bring this down to a short answer: Use `\strut` to insert a strut.